# Futures and threads, operator +

Tags: c++, future

I have a problem with my code.
Before everything compiled, but now I don't know why I'm having some  compile errors with it.

```
double function (){
    double total = 0;
    future<double> futures[n] ; 

    for( int i = 0 ; i < m ; i = i + m/n){
        futures[i%n] = futures[i%n] +  async( launch::async, function_thread,  i);
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        total = futures[i].get() + total;
    }

    return total;
}
```

And the errors are the following:

```
error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::future<double>' and 'std::future<double>')
67 |   futures[i%n] =  futures[i%n] + async(  launch::async,function_thread, i);
```

Comment: I want to store the values in future[i%n] and plus the future[i%n] value with  another value which is calculated by the i thread calling the function_thread

Comment: You can't add `future`s. Why not just make all the `future`s up front, store them to a `vector`, then iterate that and call `.get()` and sum the results? What is the goal of this cycling technique you appear to be trying to use? I can't think of any compiler that would allow what you're trying to do here.

Comment: A future != its value.  VTC as a typo.